# Can perform-sort be used within a variable declaration?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use `xsl:perform-sort` within a variable declaration, but it seems to have no effect.

Input XML:

```
<root>
    <section>
        <seq>2</seq>
    </section>
    <section>
        <seq>1</seq>
    </section>
</root>
```

Transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/*">

        <xsl:comment>using perform-sort</xsl:comment>
        <xsl:variable name="vSections" as="element() *">
            <xsl:perform-sort select="section">
                <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="seq" />
            </xsl:perform-sort>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:sequence select="$vSections/seq" />

        <xsl:comment>using for-each</xsl:comment>
        <xsl:for-each select="section">
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="seq" />
            <xsl:sequence select="seq" />
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<!--using perform-sort--><seq>2</seq><seq>1</seq><!--using for-each--><seq>1</seq><seq>2</seq>
```

I was expecting the `xsl:perform-sort` within the `vSections` variable to sort the `section` elements it contains.

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with `xsl:perform-sort`.

Comment: Interesting. Notice what happens if you do `<xsl:sequence select="$vSections" />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `<xsl:sequence select="$vSections/seq" />` you use a step `/seq` which sorts in document order (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-path-operator) so you would need `<xsl:sequence select="$vSections!seq" />` (I think it is XPath 3.0) or `<xsl:sequence select="for $s in $vSections return $s/seq" />`

Comment: In 2.0, I think you probably have to do `<xsl:for-each select="$vSections"><xsl:sequence select="seq"/></xsl:for-each>` to avoid the sort into document order.